# Validation of Swift BIC if it is SEPA reachable

Tags: payment, iban

I would like to know if there is any existing library other than SWIFT directory(As they are not free) , which will validate Swift BIC is sepa reachable.

Comment: I would guess if the BIC is for a bank in one of the SEPA member countries you should be able to use it (in combination with the IBAN) for SEPA transfers.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a free sample library for both SWIFT MT and MX messages, as well as SEPA messages and it was good enough. You can check it out [here](http://paymentcomponents.com/resources). They also have a nice documentation.